Continuous Function approximated by Lipschitz Functions
Proposition. Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$, $(x_0,y_0)$ a fixed point in $\Omega$, $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous function. Let $\alpha>0,R>0$ such that $C:=C_{\alpha,R}(x_0,y_0)\subseteq\Omega$, where $C_{\alpha,R}(x_0,y_0):=[x_0-\alpha,x_0+\alpha]\times\mathbb{B}_R(y_0)$. Let $\delta\le\delta_0$ where $\delta_0$ is the minimum between $\alpha$ and $R/M$, with $M:=\max_C||f||$. Then there exists a sequence $\{f_k:C\to\mathbb R^n\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of functions with the following properties:

$f_k$ uniformly converges to $f$ in $C$;
$||f_k||_{\infty,C}\le M$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$;
$f_k$ is locally lipschitz with respect $y$ uniformly in $x$, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

MY QUESTION. Can anyone help me in giving a rigorous and SUPERDETAILED proof of the above Proposition?
MY IDEA. For every $k$ define $f_k:C\to\mathbb R^n$ as follows

$f_k(x,y)=\frac{1}{|\mathbb{B}_{1/k}(y)\cap C|}\int_{\mathbb{B}_{1/k}(y)\cap C}f(x,u)\,du$.

I've already showed on my own that the sequence of functions so defined has properties 1 and 2, but I have no idea about how I can show that also property 3 holds (without using Divergence Theorem or Leibniz Integral Rule or something related to these tools). Maybe, it's not the right way and you can show me another way.
I've read something about the idea of using partitions of $C$ and approximating $f$ with piecewise affine functions but none of the resources that I found realize this idea in a formal, rigorous and detailed way.
I would be grateful to everyone who can help me. I need the above Proposition for the proof of Peano's Existence Theorem (about Ordinary Differential Equations).
